# Add a product category linked button to Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to add a link to single product page that goes back to category page of that product

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_single_product','add_backbtn_fcategory', 5);

function add_backbtn_fcategory(){

$category_id = get_cat_ID();

$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">BACK</a>

<?php
}
```

Effect of that is that single product page does not render below hook where the function is placed

Answer (score 2):

As you can have many product categories set for a product, you will use the following *(commented)*:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_single_product','add_back_product_category_button', 5);
function add_back_product_category_button(){

    // Get the product categories set in the product
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat' );

    // Check that there is at leat one product category set for the product
    if(sizeof($terms) > 0){
        // Get the first product category WP_Term object
        $term = reset($terms);
        // Get the term link (button link)
        $link = get_term_link( $term, 'product_cat' );

        // Button text
        $text = __('Back to','woocommerce') . ' <strong>' . $term->name . '</strong>';

        // Output
        echo '<p><a href="'.esc_url($link).'" title="'.$text.'" class="button '.$term->slug.'">'.$text.'</a></p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Code works, but in your solution if the path looks like this: " Clothing > Hoodies > Happy Ninja" - it skips the Subcategory. Is it possible to apply this Back button, for the last Subcategory instead of the Main category? Like "Back to Hoodies" in the case mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

```
global $woocommerce,$product;

$product_category_ids = wc_get_product_term_ids( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );

foreach( $product_category_ids as $cat_id ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $cat_id, 'product_cat' );

    echo $term->name;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.